# How to iterate Xml file in Java and create objects from it

Tags: java, arrays, spring, object

I have a Xml file which I iterate like this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {

        Node nNode = nList.item(i);

        System.out.println("\nCurrent Element: " + nNode.getNodeName());

        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

            Element elem = (Element) nNode;

            Node id = elem.getElementsByTagName("id").item(0);
            Node key = elem.getElementsByTagName("key").item(0);
            if (id.getTextContent().length() > 0) {
                String identifier = id.getTextContent();
                String key2 = key.getTextContent();

                System.out.println("id: " + identifier);
                System.out.println("key: " + key2);

                list.add(identifier);
                list.add(key2);

            }
        }
    }
```

That works and as you can see, I can add the values to a list of Strings but that's not what I want to do. I want to make a list of objects from those string values, lke this:

`[{"id": identifier, "key" : key2}]`.

I've tried many ways but nothing seems to work, there must be some simple way in Java also to add those strings as a key-value pairs in a list?

Comment: *"I've tried many ways"* Did any of those ways actually involve the creation of a class with the 2 fields `id` and `key`? If so, please **edit** the question and show us that attempt. If not, why would you expect to be able to create a list of objects, if you have no class for the objects?

Comment: *FYI:* You might want to look into JAXB, which is a library for mapping XML into objects. It was actually built into Java in version 8 and earlier, but you now have to add it to the classpath yourself.

Comment: Thank you @Andreas, I created a class to store those values and got it right.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

If you dont want to collect **Strings**, then say so:

```
List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

And then, instead of adding strings:

```
list.add(identifier);
list.add(key2)
```

You could do:

```
list.add(Collections.singletonMap(identifier, key2);
```

or something alike.

Comment: @MostowskiCollapse Done, didnt get the context of your question.